Incorrect Date Element is getting selected Java Selenium
I am struggling with below issue where selenium always entering date in First date field even though current list item is second.

If you looks at above data, we have 2 date fields now i can enter Availability Date without any issue, but when i am trying to enter Earliest Hire Date, it enters the date in first one. Both of these have same properties no difference except dynamic class name which we can't select.
Option tried -
1. Tried clickin on second date picker, it does click but when it
comes to enter date if enters that on first one.
2. Tried with Action, to perform both click and sendkey together. Same issues as above.
3. Tried clicking enter and clicking on List item 2 it does work but again same when
we enter date it update the date in first one.***
WebElement datePicker =positionInfoData.get(j).findElement(By.xpath("//input[@data-automation-id='dateSectionMonth-input']"));
WebElement dateField = positionInfoData.get(j).findElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-automation-id='dateTimeWidget']"));
Actions action = new Actions(DriverUtils.driver);
datePicker.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
action.moveToElement(datePicker).click().moveToElement(datePicker,200, 0).sendKeys(actionValue).build().perform();

HTML For First Element -
<input type="number" inputmode="numeric" min="1" max="12" placeholder="MM" width="2ch" tabindex="0" id="0fb600c0-f878-4c72-8e00-8454439656d3-dateSectionMonth-input" data-automation-id="dateSectionMonth-input" aria-describedby="helpText-0fb600c0-f878-4c72-8e00-8454439656d3 validationMessageContainer-56$9736--uid13" aria-label="Month" class="css-1wetivj-StyledNumericInput e1y2y4vi3" value="" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">

HTML for second
<input type="number" inputmode="numeric" min="1" max="12" placeholder="MM" width="2ch" tabindex="0" id="da687207-232b-4bf2-8e6b-e2f44ef25c40-dateSectionMonth-input" data-automation-id="dateSectionMonth-input" aria-describedby="helpText-da687207-232b-4bf2-8e6b-e2f44ef25c40" aria-label="Month" class="css-1v1ubmp-StyledNumericInput e1y2y4vi3" value="10" aria-required="true">


Hi, Can you paste the HTML source codes for these elements? This issue is usually caused by an incorrect xpath for the input. You can check the xpath in dev tool of the browser.

@Bin i have added the HTML info, i found a workaround to get it working. But i feels its not correct approach.

Hi, Your workaround is not a good solution. It just moves to the element with offset. You'd better use the xpath to locate the unique element and then input the value. The HTML codes you added are not enough. Can you add the whole HTML code including the "Availability Date", "Earliest Hire Date" labels and the 2 input area. Paste the whole HTML code in one section. Then I can help you to use the xpath to locate the input.

Finally i found some workaround to get it working, but i feel its not correct approach, so i would love to get more feedback. Sharing my solution so others can benefit from same.
My earlier approach was around list, i was focused with finding element in list and then with click enter date but with that approach it always entered date in first element. In below approach instead of list, i used text search of Date element and then using action send both click and date together.
WebElement dateFields = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Available Date')]"));
Actions action = new Actions(DriverUtils.driver);
action.moveToElement(dateFields).click().moveToElement(dateFields,200, 0).sendKeys(actionValue).build().perform();


This solution is also using the element offset as locator. it is not a good solution. You'd better use XPath Axes like "ancestor", "preceding-sibling" or "following-sibling" of the input label to locator the input. That needs you paste the whole HTML source including the label elements. Only the "input" elements are not enough to find the whole XPath.
